# How to add specific field in each firebase document to a list?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to obtain a specific field in firebase document, but I do not know how to add each one to a list. Much help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "a list". A field of type Array or of type Map? A collection of documents?

Comment: The one with the square [ ] brackets

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_11

Comment: The documentation does not help me in knowing how to add a specific field in each document of a collection to a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("YourCollection").doc("YourDocument").update({
      "anArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["data-to-add-on-your-list"])
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**